# datetime into my json mail subject c#

Tags: c#, json, parsing, datetime

This is my DateTime function. it shows you the last month. I am able to put this into my mail body but I need to have it in my subject as well. Not sure how to do this. I thought it had something to do with parsing but I am not sure.

My C#:

```
{
    var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime Uitgangstijd = BeginOfMonth(currentDate);
    DateTime Ingangstijd = Uitgangstijd.AddMonths(-1);

    var totDatum = Uitgangstijd;
    var retrieveDate = Ingangstijd;
    var dataItems = GetFromDatabase(retrieveDate, totDatum);
    var usageReport = new Core.Database.Report()
    {
        DatumVan = retrieveDate,
        DatumTot = totDatum,
        UsageItems = dataItems,
    };
    SetInDatabase(Report);
    Send(JobCancellationToken.Null, Report);

    DateTime t = BeginOfMonth(Ingangstijd);
}

private DateTime BeginOfMonth(DateTime t)
{
   return new DateTime(t.Year, t.Month, 1);
}
```

My JSON:

```
"Details": {
    "MailConfig": {
    "Addresses": {
      "From": "info@xxx.com",
      "To": [ "xxx@xxx.com" ],
      "CC": [],
      "BCC": []
    },
      "Subject": "Statistics_(DateTime function here)_2017"
    },
      "MailBaseUrl": "http://localhost/WebApp"
    }
}
```

Populating my Json:

```
   public class DetailSettings
  {
    public MailConfig MailConfig { get; set; }
    public string MailBaseUrl { get; set; }
  }
  }  
  public class MailConfig
  {
    public Addresses Addresses { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }
  }
  }
  public class Addresses
  {
    public string From { get; set; }
    public List<string> To { get; set; }
    public List<string> CC { get; set; }
    public List<string> BCC { get; set; }
      }
   }
```

Comment: How do you populate your JSON object?

Comment: I populated it like this. ^

Comment: Isn't `var beginOfMonth = BeginOfMonth(Ingangstijd); string subject = "Statistics_" + beginOfMonth.ToString() + "_2017";`doing the job here ?

Comment: it does if i want to write it to the body. But the problem is that i need to define the subject in my .json file whom i dont know how to do at this point.

Comment: @SennerP: Your json is a static data file once generated - your json can't do extra calculations. So you need to generate your subject before you put it into the json or generate it after you load up your json.

Comment: @Chris I See thank you, the issue is tho that this code fires itsself up on the first of each month. The problem with this is that each month's report subject has to contain a different month like: Statistics_Januari_2017, Statistics_Februari_2017 etc. So you are saying this is not a possibility?

Comment: I may be confused about what you are after. ChristopherJ.'s suggestion to just set your subject with the month in will totally work. You seemed to suggest that this wasn't working and that you "needed to define the subject in your .json file". I interpreted this as meaning that you wanted to have the json file be able to execute code that generated the date which is not possible - json files don't execute code. Could you explain your comment "it does if I want to write it to the body" perhaps - explain why you can write to the body but not the subject...

Comment: @Chris nevermind, i'm probably not bringing this right. I'll try and fix it on my own. Thanks anyway

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you explained what you are doing with your JSON. eg is there a reason you generate a single json file that is used for multiple purposes which is why you can't write the date into it?

Comment: @Chris Because it has to work together with the rest of the file. The rest of the file i generated to be able to read and process certain EDI files. After these are processed all the data(from that month) will be put in a .CSV file and attached to the E-mail. as what Christopher said works for my body(Which i already made). the subject is the thing i need to change through this JSON file or the whole program collapses you see.

Comment: I am unclear though why you can't generate the correct subject string with the right date in when you create the json file.

Comment: Because the date is different each month. therefor the subject is different each time the Job is executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is to fill the subject, fill it from C# code, like the following :

Your classes :

```
public class DetailSettings
{
    public MailConfig MailConfig { get; set; }
    public string MailBaseUrl { get; set; }

    public DetailSettings()
    {
        MailConfig = new MailConfig();
    }
}

public class MailConfig
{
    public Addresses Addresses { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```

Then create instance and fill it then use serialization :

```
DetailSettings detailsSettings = new DetailSettings();
DateTime t = BeginOfMonth(DateTime.Now);
detailsSettings.MailConfig.Subject =string.Format("Statistics_{0}_{1}", t,t.Year);
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(detailsSettings);
```